# How does reversing a std::string in C++ works with this constructor?

Tags: c++, stdstring

```
std::string original;
std::string reversed(original.rbegin(), original.rend());
```

I have found this method for reversing a `std::string` but I don't understand how it works. Can you provide me with an explanation?

Comment: What exactly is unclear here? Have you read the relevant documentation?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: What parts is it you don't understand? How [`rbegin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin) and [`rend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rend) work? How the `std::string` constructor works and what overloads of it there are? Something else?

Comment: they are reverse iterators, you can say "rbegin" is equivalent of "end". read here:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/rbegin/

Comment: sorry, string is not a vector you would think, but does a similar iteration there :)

Comment: too many comments, but only to help you, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rbegin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code:

```
std::string original;
std::string reversed(original.rbegin(), original.rend());
```

The [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that is called is:

```
template< class InputIt >
basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

> Constructs the string with the contents of the range `[first, last)`.

Therefore, the iterator range `[original.rbegin(), original.rend())` will be used. [`rbegin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin) and [`rend()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rend) return *reversed* iterators. This means that the range will start from the last character of the original string and end at the first character (`rend()` points to the previous character to that, which will not be accessed by the constructor since that side of the interval is open).